# Filter based on gender

Tags: maatwebsite-excel

In my Excel sheet has a Gender column. I want to get only "Male" entries but when importing the data via maatwebsite, my code displays all the results.

How can I filter the results properly?

```
$data = Excel::load($path, function ($reader){
    $results = $reader->get(array('user_url','gender'=>'Male')))->take(10);
    if (!empty($results)) {
        foreach ($results as $val => $link) {
            $userid = $link['fb_unique_id'];
            print_r($userid);
        }
    }
}
```